# Selenium: Need valid image location/path of an image file placed on a website

Tags: selenium, web, captcha

I am able to find img tag using iwebdriver.findElement() query. Image contains captcha.
I also get the src attribute which contains the url of image but it is not working when i open it it gives me 404 error.

This is the img tag i am looking for and i need its valid image path.

{img src="https://EU1.client.hip.live.com/GetHIPData?hid=EU1.d3f00459fcb444fc8efb402f3c2dc237&fid=bbc4f6c344e7434c9b712c2d80f7268c&id=274850&type=visual&hdid=0&rnd=1798e82f1c7d4d51922f1a58c03c4d74" style="display: inline; width: 218px; height: 48px;" id="wlspispHIPBimg05f4e37f6e1bc431d8c335e2d169a0f440"}

```
// Assuming webdriver is set and running

IWebdriver _driver=new firefoxdriver(capabilities);

_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url");

IWebElement img_tag = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("img[style='display: inline; width: 218px; height: 48px;']"));

// Now i have the entire img tag required which contains a image.

string source_path=img_tag.GetAttribute("src");

// Now i have src url of image. but it does not show the image when i go to this source path. This is the relative path of the image i think.
```

Comment: Please provide more details and the code you have at the moment. Otherwise - it is too broad.

Comment: Find the image src url don't means the url can be used, the image may be removed, so you got a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've opened the page you'r visiting. As you're trying to get captcha image. You won't be able to get image from captcha image source.

You have to get screenshot of page and crop the captcha image.
Don't use css selector with width and height. Some pages are responsive, it will put you in trouble. Use XPath instead.

```
public Image GetCaptchaImage()
{
    Image imgCap = null;
    try
    {
        var arrScreen = driver.GetScreenshot().AsByteArray;
        using (var msScreen = new MemoryStream(arrScreen))
        {
            var bmpScreen = new Bitmap(msScreen);
            var cap = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='ispHIPHIP']//img"));
            var rcCrop = new Rectangle(cap.Location, cap.Size);
            imgCap = bmpScreen.Clone(rcCrop, bmpScreen.PixelFormat);

        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return imgCap;
}
```